# Moving/migrating VDO disk to another server

Tags: vdo

Following…

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/vdo-quick-start

I’m able to setup/configure VDO.

I’m unable to find any documentation for moving the physical disk (created/configured through VDO on a server) to another server.

Basically I used LVM to create volumes on top of VDO disk. Now I have moved the physical disk to another server (which has VDO as a package installed), but it doesn't scans/detects the VDO volume.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by copying the /etc/vdoconf.yml to the other host.